# Display array from code behind to aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I right now have an array that I would like to display on my aspx page. When making my table on my aspx I need to have it so that it takes the size of my array regardless of how many rows. I am not sure how to do this, besides looping through my array to find values/size. How would I push my array to display the contents on my webpage?

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Service1 myService = new Service1();
            string passed_value = Request.QueryString["parameter"];

            //runs to get array
            //returns array
            string[][] array;
            array = myService.Get_Array(passed_value);

        }
```

array for example:

```
@[0][0]123
@[0][1]C:\file\file_name.txt
@[0][2]file_name
```

and so on..

aspx just has a div for the table, I know how to make a table but not one that is dynamic. Sorry it's not much.

```
  <div class="table">

  </div>
```

Comment: Use `GridView`.

Comment: That should solve my issues, I didn't know my options. @PawanNogariya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was using GridView thanks to @Pawan Nogariya. I hope this helps future users who are trying to display arrays since there are not many solutions unless you know about GridView.

ASPX:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="Grid" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns = "false" Font-Names = "Arial"
    Font-Size = "11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#C2D69B" 
    HeaderStyle-BackColor = "green" AllowPaging ="true"  
    PageSize = "10">
   <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px"
     DataField = "ID" HeaderText = "ID" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px"
     DataField = "Path" HeaderText = "Path" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px"
     DataField = "Name" HeaderText = "Name" />
   </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
```

Codebehind:

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt.Columns.Add("Path", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add();
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["ID"] = array[i][0];
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Path"] = array[i][1];
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Name"] = array[i][2];
            }
            Grid.DataSource = dt;
            Grid.DataBind();
```